# Extract date from a text document in R

Tags: r, image, image-processing

I am again here with an interesting problem.

I have a document like shown below:

"""UDAYA FILLING STATION ps\na MATTUPATTY ROAD oe\noe 4 MUNNAR Be:\nSeat 4 04865230318 Rat\nBree 4 ORIGINAL bepas e\n\noe: Han Die MC DE ER DC I se ek OO UO a Be ten\" % aot\n: ag ***29-MAY-2019*** 14:02:23 [i\n— INVOICE NO: 292 hee fos\nae VEHICLE NO: NOT ENTERED Bea\nss NOZZLE NO : 1 ome\n- PRODUCT: PETROL ae\ne RATE : 75.01 INR/Ltr yee\n“| VOLUME: 1.33 Ltr ae\n~ 9 =6AMOUNT: 100.00 INR mae wae\nage, Ee pel Di EE I EE oe NE BE DO DC DE a De ee De ae Cate\notome S.1T. No : 27430268741C =. ver\nnes M.S.T. No: 27430268741V ae\n\nThank You! Visit Again\n""""

From the above document, I need to extract date highlighted in bold and Italics.

I tried with strpdate function but did not get the desired results.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only want to capture a single date, you may use `sub` here:

```
text <- "UDAYA FILLING STATION ps\na MATTUPATTY ROAD oe\noe 4 MUNNAR Be:\nSeat 4 04865230318 Rat\nBree 4 ORIGINAL bepas e\n\noe: Han Die MC DE ER DC I se ek OO UO a Be ten\" % aot\n: ag 29-MAY-2019 14:02:23 [i\n— INVOICE NO: 292 hee fos\nae VEHICLE NO: NOT ENTERED Bea\nss NOZZLE NO : 1 ome\n- PRODUCT: PETROL ae\ne RATE : 75.01 INR/Ltr yee\n“| VOLUME: 1.33 Ltr ae\n~ 9 =6AMOUNT: 100.00 INR mae wae\nage, Ee pel Di EE I EE oe NE BE DO DC DE a De ee De ae Cate\notome S.1T. No : 27430268741C =. ver\nnes M.S.T. No: 27430268741V ae\n\nThank You! Visit Again\n"
date <- sub("^.*\\b(\\d{2}-[A-Z]+-\\d{4})\\b.*", "\\1", text)
date

[1] "29-MAY-2019"
```

If you had the need to match *multiple* such dates in your text, then you may use `regmatches` along with `regexec`:

```
text <- "Hello World 29-MAY-2019 Goodbye World 01-JAN-2018"
regmatches(text,regexec("\\b(\\d{2}-[A-Z]+-\\d{4})\\b", text))[[1]]

[1] "29-MAY-2019" "29-MAY-2019"
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, just curious How to use sub to extract date in any given format like "29-05-2019" or "05-29-2019" or "2019-05-29" or "2019-29-05"

Comment: @kiranu That's a totally different question and not what you asked.  You should open a new question if you also need help with date cleanup.